# One point compactification is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

I am starting to study the one point compactification of a $T_1$ space $S$, namely $S^*=S \cup\{\infty\}$.

I understand most of it except the part about $S^*$ being compact.

1. Given $C=\{A/A$ is open on $S^*$ $\}$ an open cover for $S^*$, at least one lets call it $A_{1}$ contains $\infty$.
2. Take all $A\in C$ such that $A \neq A_1$ then since $S^*-A_1=B$ is closed and compact on $S$ any open cover for $B$ has a finite subcover.
3. Also take $D=\{A\cap S/ A\in C\}$ then $D$ covers $B$. By the previous step $B=\cup(A_i\cap S)$ for $i=2,...,n$.
4. Now $\{A_1,A_2,...,A_n\}$ covers $S^*$.

I need help understanding 3 and 4. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you have for 1 and 2. Why is 3/4 hard for you?

Comment: 1. It is clear to me that since $\infty$ belongs in $S^*$ at least one element of the cover must also contain it. Also in 2. $B$ is defined that way, and that is just the definition of compactness of $B$. For 3. I kind of get it because every element in $B$ is not in $A_1$ then it is in the union of elements in $D$. But 4. I just dont see it.

Comment: This does give a proof but the basic idea of a one-point compactification is such that you define a point, not in your space such that every sequence in some sense is convergent, in the sense that you define a boundary for your divergent sequences such that everything works fine.  This idea is related to metric spaces and convergence, but I think that this gives a good insight.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in 3). Instead of $A\cup S$ it should be $A\cap S$. Since $B \subset S$ and $B \subset S^{*}$ 3) follows from the fact that $D$ covers $S^{*}$. 4) follows from the fact that $S^{*} \subset B  \cup A_1$.

Comment: corrected the typo, thanks.